# Add a new view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

My question will probably sounds dumb to most of you but I have been struggling to find out the problem. I basically have a method and a view (created by right click-> Add View).

This is my method:

```
public ActionResult yearlyOverview(FormCollection values)
{
    return View();
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    yearlyOverview
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    
    <h2>yearlyOverview</h2>
</asp:Content>
```

The error message that I get comes from the browser:

> `Sys.ArgumentException`: `Sys.ArgumentException`: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON. Parameter name: data

This is the master page code:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>PS Administration</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Notices", "Index", "Notice")%></li>
                    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Job Positions", "Index", "JobPosition")%></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody already stumbled on this problem?

Comment: Nothing wrong with view - you need to investigate more and update question. This error have nothing to adding new view, but rather what you render in your view... Seem to be an issue with some "data" object not properly created, possibly this information is needed by master page portion of the view.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - you can have Page directives in an ASP.NET MVC view? Or is it only valid if you are using the WebForms view engine? Razor would not understand those, right?

Comment: @KarlAnderson Razor will not understand those page directives.

Comment: Post your master page code.

Comment: when you added a view using right clik, what option you selected for : View Data Class ?

Comment: When I added the view I selected ASPX (C#) as view Engine

Comment: I wonder how your question has been up-voted. You are mixing asp.net mvc with classic asp.net.

Comment: @KarlAnderson - with Razor you can get into similar issue ("some random requirements coming from master view") when your "_layout" page introduces requirements (like adding some script that requires particular object to be rendered by page's code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my code was good but the mistake i made was to call the form using ajax.beginForm instead of a normal form, and I was trying to parse an object data that wasn't returned by the controller.